# Day and night zone layer for Leaflet

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, geojson

I'm working with Leaflet and I'd like to show the day and night zones adding a dynamic layer to my map. I was thinking to add a static layer with some transparency and make it move every x minutes but it's tricky because the shape of the shadow... changes all the time during the year.

Does anyone know if there exists some open source layers for every season or better if I could find a way to calculate an accurate geojson layer for the earth's shadow ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a plugin for that: [Leaflet.Terminator](http://joergdietrich.github.io/Leaflet.Terminator/).

Comment: Is there anything that is not present as a plugin for leaflet?

Comment: @Ilja Zverev, thanks a lot it works perfectly ! a snapshot of the result here : https://twitter.com/PopTweetsLive